# Possible to accept/pass in a list of accounts to program API?

Tags: anchor, solana-program, account

```
pub struct Example<'info>{
    pub mint: Account<'info, Mint>,
    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
    pub token_program: Program<'info, Token>,
    pub rent: Sysvar<'info, Rent>,
    pub associated_token: Program<'info, AssociatedToken>,
}
```

If I want my Anchor Context to accept more accounts, do I need to always explicitly add them?

Or is there another way to pass in a List of the same account types?
I.e. pub mint: Vec<Account<'info, Mint>>

Also, I heard that there is a limit of 30 accounts. Is this correct?

Comment: How would you manage your constraints if you were to pass it in as a vector? Is it really a good idea to do something like this?

Comment: `Also, I heard that there is a limit of 30 accounts. Is this correct?` this is a separate question, feel free to ask this in a new question

Comment: @Meow good question, is it possible to add acc constraints if Accounts are in a vector?